# How to Self Host a ASP.NET Core WebAPI with Console App?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a fully functional ASP.NET Core Web API built with .NET 8, and it runs smoothly in Visual Studio. Now, I'm looking to create a separate console application to host this Web API using self-hosting.

Could someone please provide guidance or code examples on how to achieve this with .NET 8? I appreciate any insights or best practices you can share.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I'm looking to create a separate console application to host this Web API using self-hosting.

You don't need an extra console application, ASP.NET Core app is a console application which can be run as is. It comes with [build-in Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

> Kestrel is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core. Kestrel is the recommended server for ASP.NET Core, and it's configured by default in ASP.NET Core project templates.

So just run the built/published app (with proper config) and that's it.

See also:

- [Web server implementations in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows)
- [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thank you for Fast response. I'm currently working on a university project and need to create a separate console application to host my ASP.NET Core Web API, as per the project requirements. I'm seeking practical guidance or code examples specific to this scenario. Any help or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: @MikloWak This is a bit strange requirement. Possibly it is dated and should not be followed. Can you please provide the full text of the requirement. If not - I would ask the author of the task for clarifications since in the current wording the requirement does not make much sense to me.